# Dynamic Elasticsearch Query for grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I want to display the count of all records from elasticsearch where
message has this following keyword "time taken in millis==>124" and the value 124 is dynamic, meaning the value after "==>" should be in range of 100 to 200.

Is there any way to display the count in grafana using lucene query?

I want the count of all the records in a grafana graph using lucene query.